# Convert a angular application to a module

Tags: angularjs, iframe, module, bower, angular-bootstrap

I've developed two angular applications:

- Contacts
- MailClient

Both need to be deployed on their own endpoints. However: MailClient has a tab that needs to load Contacts and communication should be possible between the Contacts tab and the MailClient.

What is the best way to achieve this?
I first thought of using an iFrame and use angular.bootstrap to load a second angular application, but I've read that "*AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.*"

So my second thought was to somehow convert the the Contacts-app to a module/component (bower?) which can be loaded in the MailClient. But how to achieve this? Or are there other (better) alternatives (like configuring the MailClient project to use symbolic links to the Contact project and just use them in the project - I don't now how we would configure the build-server in that case though)?

Comment: Did you try the iframe solution? The iframe is a separate document and If I'm not mistaken, there is no nesting with this

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but thanks for the info! This would still leave me with the problem that communication is needed between the two apps. (for example: a send message-link from the Contacts page should trigger a sendMessage popup from MailClient

Comment: I would suggest not using an iFrame because thats just dirty programming. There are however ways that you can turn your Contacts into a module that can be inherited by another module using injectors in angularjs. Take a look at angularjs module injection